# how to use scrapy package with Juypter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, scrapy, jupyter

I'm trying to learn web scraping/crawling and trying to apply the below code on Juypter Notebook but it didn't show any outputs, So can anyone help me and guide me to how to use the scrapy package on Juypter notebook.

**The code:**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class BooksCrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'books_crawl'
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/sequential-art_5/page-1.html']

    le_book_details = LinkExtractor(restrict_css='h3 > a')
    le_next = LinkExtractor(restrict_css='.next > a')  # next_button
    le_cats = LinkExtractor(restrict_css='.side_categories > ul > li > ul > li a')  # Categories

    rule_book_details = Rule(le_book_details, callback='parse_item', follow=False)
    rule_next = Rule(le_next, follow=True)
    rule_cats = Rule(le_cats, follow=True)

    rules = (
        rule_book_details,
        rule_next,
        rule_cats
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'Title': response.css('h1 ::text').get(),
            'Category': response.xpath('//ul[@class="breadcrumb"]/li[last()-1]/a/text()').get(),
            'Link': response.url
        }
```

**The final result is without any output:-**

[image]

Comment: A simple and effective way would be the use of an api, sometimes the easiest way is just to ask the provider. Since it is quite an extensive collection, it can take a while and if necessary you should not tackle everything in one fell swoop but in chunks, not least to work with some consideration for the infrastructure of the target. What is the focus of the question or what error messages are there.

Comment: I'm trying to learn web scraping and read a little about web crawling and scrapy package.. I think it can extract the full data that i need through the linked pages but i still can't find the right way.. So if you can guide me, i would be appreciated

Comment: You can extract and there is no right way. Issue with you post is, there is no specific error described, it will lead to fact-based answers. Help us to help you by improving your question and focus your example. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] and [ask] Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run your spider you can add the following snippet in a new cell:

```py
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(BooksCrawlSpider)
process.start()
```

[More details on the Scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html)

---

Edit:

A solution to create a dataframe from the extracted items would be  first exporting the output to a file (eg. .CSV), by passing the `settings` parameter to CrawlerProcess:

```py
process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    "FEEDS": {
        "items.csv": {"format": "csv"},
    },
})
```

Then open it with pandas:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("items.csv")
```

Comment: Many thanks, it work for me but do you have any idea about how to transform the output to DataFrame as when i try to use pd.DataFrame(process.crawl(BooksCrawlSpider)) it gives me an error "ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!"

Comment: Just edited it to add an idea on that